# Serializing Multiple Objects into ByteArray

Tags: vb.net, serialization, deserialization

I am wondering one thing; How can I serialize multiple objects to a byte array. My goal is to send the serialized object over tcp, receive it, then deserialize it, and recreate it.
My concept is:
The first thing in the byte array will be the "Packet Header" -- This will tell the receiver what type of packet it is; "Chat Message", "File Transfer", etc etc. Then after the header I will add the packet itself. Then at last there will be an "EOF Header" (This will tell the server if the whole packet is received). - The headers are enumerables(as Byte).

Comment: if they are actual Object types, you will have problems.  Otherwise, a class, List or most other containers with your data in it are much easier to serialize than you expect.

Comment: Do u have an example of serializing a list?

Answer (score 0):

**where** you get these errors would be helpful (essential even) but it is probably related to this:

```
    Public Shared Function Deserialize(Data As Byte()) As Packet
        Dim MS As New MemoryStream(Data)
        Dim BF As New BinaryFormatter
        MS.Position = 0
        ' or
        'MS.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
        Return DirectCast(BF.Deserialize(MS), Packet)
    End Function
```

After seeding the memstream, the stream position is left at the end.  You need to reset it so the BF can read all the bytes.  (and you really dont need things like BOF and EOF in the serialized data - even if you are sending multiple things, if you put them in a list, they will either de/serialize *in toto* or not).

Also look at ProtoBuf-NET - much faster serializer making much smaller packets, and it will let you deserialize into a different assembly-culture-class which NET's BF does not do without basically tricking it.